# how to fetch all the documents below a specific doc from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how can we fetch all the document after a specific document from firebase flutter ? what I mean is for example we have 10 documents with respective id  and order[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in firebase I want to fetch documents from [1 to 5]once then [6 to 10] in next call .some thing for state management loading a certain number of documents once then another range of documents in next call and so on and reflect in User Interface accordingly.
please help me in this regards..

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has a `startAfterDocument` method that can be used to query collections after a certain index based on the document. You can first query the collection and set limit to the number of documents retrieved using
`firestore.collection('example').limit(5).get()`. With this result you can store the last document and use it for the next queries as such:
`firestore.collection('example').startAfterDocument(lastDocumentInPreviousQuery).limit(5)`

Just make sure you always store the last document that was retrieved in a query to ensure you get the correct result.

Comment: thank you i will try it and let you know

Comment: Thank you very much.. it worked.. but one extra query .. do we have any way in firebase to fetch documents below by referencing document id instead of document snapshot ?@Santiago Racca

Comment: If you know the document id (which in your case you do) You can make a reference to the document 
`firestore.collection('example').doc(1)`

You can then use `startAtSnapshot` instead of `startAfterSnapshot` to query the documents. You just have to be sure to pass in the correct id which corresponds to the document you want to start at

Comment: when i try to use startAfterSnapshot it gives with the error : The method 'startAfterSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.